# How does spring-retry determine which methods to retry when @Retryable is placed at the class level?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have a `@Retryable` placed at the class level.

```
@Import({GrpcClientRetryConfig.class})
@Retryable(interceptor = "grpcClientRetryInterceptor")
@Component
public class Profile {
    public void method1() {
        method2();
    }

    public void method2() {
        val msg = "Hello World";
        System.out.println(msg);
        throw new RunTimeException("Testing");
    }
}

@EnableRetry
@Configuration
public class GrpcClientRetryConfig {
 @Bean
 public RetryOperationsInterceptor grpcClientRetryInterceptor() {
    val template = new RetryTemplate();
    val backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
    // Set the exponential backoff parameter
    val interceptor = new RetryOperationsInterceptor();
    val simpleRetry = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    simpleRetry.setMaxAttempts(2);
    template.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetry);
    template.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    template.setListeners(new GrpcClientRetryListener[] {new GrpcClientRetryListener()});
    interceptor.setRetryOperations(template);
    return interceptor;
 }
}
```

**Case 1**

```
val profile = new Profile();
profile.method2(); // Hello World printed twice an exception is thrown
```

**Case 2**

```
val profile = new Profile();
profile.method1(); // Hello World printed twice and then an exception is thrown
```

A sample project is placed [here](https://github.com/debraj-manna/spring-boot-hello-world). Please check `com.example.helloworld.controller.HelloWorldController#sendGreetings`

Should not `Hello World` be printed 4 times? `method1()` calls `method2()`. `method2()` gets retried 2 times and then throws the exception to `method1()` which again calls `method2()` one more time?

Can someone let me know why `method1()` is not retried twice in the second case? How does spring determine which methods to be retried when a `@Retryable` is placed at the class level?